# unable to download media file using url in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

Unable to download media file in angular 7, i have link url but using my code some i am unable to download vedio file, in some blog answer open media in new tab, below is my code

```
              this.vedio = "https://myvio/njk.mp4"
              let blob = new Blob([this.video], { type: 'application/octet'});
              let link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              link.download = "https://myvio/njk.mp4;
              link.target = "_self"
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
              document.body.removeChild(link);
```

using my code dummy media file(in bytes 142) will be downloaded, i need to download complete file size(in Mbs)
when button click

Answer (score 0):

You coud use file-saver

1. Install file-saver

> npm install file-saver --save
>
> npm install @types/file-saver --save

Component:

```
public downloadFile(file: File): Observable<Blob> {
   return this.http.get(file.fullPath, {responseType: 'blob'})
}
```

Comment: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Not Allowed